# Enum e default não funciona?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Saudações dev's, eu tenho o seguinte schema no meu app:

```
const customerModel = new Schema({
    ...
    roles: [{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['user', 'admin'],
        default: 'user'
    }]
})
```

Porém quando eu insiro num novo customer, se eu não passo um valor para roles invés de ser retornado o valor default = 'user' é retornado um array vazio.

Os dados estão sendo salvos em um arquivo separado assim:

```
exports.createCustomer = async (data) => {
    const customer = new Customer(data)

    await customer.save()
}
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado aqui ?

Comment: [Isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656647/how-to-configure-default-enum-value-in-mongoose-sub-doc) ajuda seu problema?

Comment: roles não deveria ser um único objeto?